# Flickering on simple triangle render in openGL

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, doublebuffered

Our current assignment requires us to use older fixed-pipeline methods in openGL. We're using LWJGL 2.9.3. The following code displays a triangle. The problem is, it flickers like crazy. The Display.swapBuffers() method doesn't throw an exception, and it doesn't make any difference if I include it or not. I created this example based off this StackOverflow question:

[gluPerspective, glViewport, gluLookAt and the GL_PROJECTION and GL_MODELVIEW Matricies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053334/gluperspective-glviewport-glulookat-and-the-gl-projection-and-gl-modelview-mat)

```
glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 10, 0, 10, -1, 100);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3d(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3d(1, 5, 1);
    glVertex3d(5, 5, 1);
glEnd();
glFlush();
try {
    Display.swapBuffers();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**

One other thing. If I call glLoadIdentity() after glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW), it's as if the gluLookAt() method is ignored. I just see a blank black screen if I do that. But if I don't, it keeps multiplying with itself (if I change the eye position from 0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the flickering was that the gluLookAt() function was swapping back and forth between looking different directions.

Comment: So basically you had to add `glLoadIdentity()` and then figured out that `gluLookAt` looked in the wrong direction?

Comment: Yeah. It was looking in the wrong direction. If the eye is at (0,0,0), and the look-at point is at (0,1,0), then it is looking down the Y axis. The polygon  was parallel to the X/Y plane. I put a 1 in the wrong place.